# How to Write function with class parament

Tags: c++

I have a class like this

```
struct Stop
{
    int x,y,distanceFromStart,index;
    bool isStart,isStop;
    vector<Stop*> adjencyVec;
    Stop(int x,int y,int i) :x(x),y(y),isStart(false),isStop(false),distanceFromStart(INT_MAX),index(i)
    {

    }
};
```

I would like to write a universal function for binary search. 
There will be two variants of this function:

```
int binarySearchForX(vector<Stop*> &arr, int l, int r, int valueToFind); 
int binarySearchForY(vector<Stop*> &arr, int l, int r, int valueToFind);
```

which only differ in two lines. `binarySearchForX` checks the `x` field:

```
if (arr[mid]->x == valueToFind)
    //..............
if (arr[mid]->x > valueToFind)
   //..............
```

and `binarySearchForY` checks `y`.

I was thinking to passing a predicate or something like this.
My question is how to make it possible in one function.

Comment: Not directly connected to the question, but who is managing the memory of the Stops? Since Stop isn't an interface, you can just put std::vector<Stop> and not a vector of pointers, and let the vector handle the memory allocations.

Comment: Just to be sure, you're aware of [`lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound). This, combined with a lambda, already does what `binarySearchForX` and `binarySearchForY` are supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [pointer to member variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_pointer-to-member_access_operators):

```
Stop* commonSearch(int Stop::* fld, Stop* s, int val) {
   if (s->*fld == val)
     return s;
   return nullptr; // TODO: actually binary search.
}

Stop* binarySearchForX(Stop* s, int x) {
    return commonSearch(&Stop::x, s, x);
}
Stop* binarySearchForY(Stop* s, int y) {
    return commonSearch(&Stop::y, s, y);
}
```

You can also use `std::invoke(fld, s)` if you have C++17.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for.